# Error found then loading /etc/profile

Tags: bash, login, dell, 22.10

An error was encountered while loading /etc/profile:
tr: symbol lookup error: tr: undefined symbol: waiting, version GLIBC_2.2.5
The result of the session will be the wrong mood.
You need to fix the problem as soon as possible.

[image]

Comment: This is a user support Q&A site; how is that a question?   If you want to report a bug, you should submit a bug report on a site read by developers (ie. a bug tracker).  There is no question here that we can answer that I can see. I'd suggest reading https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @guiverc I dont want to report a bug. I encountered an error after user authorization. Above, I literally wrote the text of the error that appeared. I want to know how to fix this.

Comment: @Terrance I do have a copy of default profile in /usr/share/base-files

Comment: Copy the `profile` file from that directory replacing the one in the `/etc/` directory.

Comment: @Terrance nothing changed

Comment: `/etc/profile` is not loaded every time you launch a terminal.  It is loaded at time of boot.  You will have to reboot your system for the changes to take effect.

Comment: @Terrance I rebooted the system. Nothing changed. In boot logs everything is "OK". I can attache some screenshots if it would help

Comment: I would look in the `/etc/bash.bashrc` file for any line starting with `tr` or look at any file contained in the `/etc/profile.d/` directory for any file containing the `tr` as whatever is calling that is where it is failing.

Comment: @Terrance I added a screenshot in my question. It is the only thing i've found.

Comment: At this point, it honestly sounds like a bug like @guiverc pointed out.  Everything looks good there that I can see.

Comment: `tr: symbol lookup error` suggests a problem with the `tr` executable itself, or one of its shared libraries. What do `type -a tr` and `ldd "$(type -p tr)"` output?

Comment: @steeldriver
`tr is /usr/bin/tr`
`tr is /bin/tr`

`linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff28f58000)`
 `libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fad09c00000)`
 `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fad09fdb000)`